# align self not aligning?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm stumped I'm trying to learn flexbox and I cant get align self to work at all... there has to be some thing I'm missing. when i find it I'm going to drown it in my own tears

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>vaugn's emporium ol' stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
        
        <div class="logo">
            <a class="header" </a>
        </div>

        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css code**

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    border-style: solid;
    color: grey;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo{
    border-style: solid;
    align-self: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox contents, by default, are arranged in rows. The horizontal position of the content boxes is controlled by `justify-content`. Their vertical position is controlled by align-items (and `align-self`, if desired). If you specify `flex-direction: column` on the flexbox, then these are reversed, with `justify-content` controlling vertical positioning, and `align-items`/`align-self` controlling horizontal positioning.

So to get the logo to appear on the right side, you should set `justify-content: end` on your `.container`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  border-style: solid;
  color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/100">
  </div>
</div>
```